# Bootstrap font awesome in textbox not working properly with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form in which i have used text boxes with the label and it is not working properly. If i removed the font awesome icon which is inside the span tag it is working properly this is my html

[image: bootstrap font awesome]

```
            <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to do something like this [image: final image]

https://jsbin.com/quxodidebi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How does it not work properly? The screenshot of the two situations look rather alike to me.

Comment: the label should be in one line and the textbox should be another line with the fontawesome icon

Comment: Could You please make exact example in paint? I don't understand the comment description either.

Comment: ok i can make it for you give me a second

Comment: @Tatranskymedved i have updated the question also i have make the image how i want to do it

Comment: @MrLister i have updated the question also i have make the image how i want to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this code? Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
</div>
</div>
```

**Code snippet:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sefnanLm/

Comment: i am using bootstrap 4

Comment: Nice answer, I edited it and added a snippet and JS fiddle example.